# curl: could not resolve host: salesforce and db_key

Tags: api, curl, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I am attempting to configure my postgres database key and schema for my connection with a heroku server. Now I am trying to obtain my auth token by using a curl request such as so:

```
curl -X PATCH -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"schema_name": "salesforce", "db_key": "DATABASE_URL"}' https://connect-3-virginia.heroku.com/api/v3/connections/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXX-XXXXXXXX
```

I have also tried wrapping the url in "" marks and I receive the same error. The error is below: Can anyone tell me what is wrong that is giving me this error?

```
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: salesforce, curl: (6) Could not resolve host: db_key curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 13
{"message":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}
```